# How to get previous day using datetime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datetime

I want to set a `DateTime` property to the previous day at time 00:00:00. I've tried using `DateTime.AddDays(-1)` and `DateTime.AddTicks(-1)` and they aren't working. Is this the right way to do it?

I have 2 objects. Each object has two `DateTime` fields: `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo`.

EDIT: After coming home from work I tried to get the same behavior as my business objects. The code I used to try and replicate how it functions at work is below. Of course this is working at home but not at work. The good thing is I got good answers and +1 on all! =)

```
public class RuleValue
{
    public DateTime ValidFrom, ValidTo;
    
    public RuleValue(DateTime _validFrom, DateTime _validTo)
    {
        ValidFrom = _validFrom;
        ValidTo = _validTo;
    }

    // oldObject.ValidFrom = 1900-01-01
    // oldObject.ValidTo = 9999-12-31

    // newObject.ValidFrom = 2010-03-22
    // newObject.ValidTo = 9999-12-31
    public void ChangeOldDate(RuleValue oldObject, RuleValue newObject)
    {
        /* 
         * 1: When first object (oldObject) have ValidTo set to SQL-server maxdate (9999-12-12 23:59:59 etc)
         *    I want to allow for a new object to be created
         * 2: oldObject timespan ValidFrom-ValidTo should not be overlapping with newObjects timespan(i have checks for that)
         * 3: oldObject.ValidTo should be newObject.ValidFrom - one day/or one tick
         */

        if (oldObject.ValidTo == DateTime.MaxValue)
        {
            oldObject.ValidTo = newObject.ValidFrom.AddTicks(-1); //now works
        } 
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RuleValue rv1 = new RuleValue(DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01"), DateTime.MaxValue);
        RuleValue rv2 = new RuleValue(DateTime.Parse("2010-03-22"), DateTime.MaxValue);

        Console.WriteLine("First: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Old = " + rv1.ValidFrom + " - " + rv1.ValidTo);
        Console.WriteLine("New = " + rv2.ValidFrom + " - " + rv2.ValidTo);
        
        rv1.ChangeOldDate(rv1, rv2);

        Console.WriteLine("After: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Old = " + rv1.ValidFrom + " - " + rv1.ValidTo);
        Console.WriteLine("New = " + rv2.ValidFrom + " - " + rv2.ValidTo);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
//Output:
//First:
//Old = 1900-01-01 00:00:00 - 9999-12-31 23:59:59
//New = 2010-03-22 00:00:00 - 9999-12-31 23:59:59
//After:
//Old = 1900-01-01 00:00:00 - 2010-03-21 23:59:59
//New = 2010-03-22 00:00:00 - 9999-12-31 23:59:59
//  ALL CORRECT! :D
```

Comment: can we see your code for DataTime.AddDays(-1) ?

Comment: `AddDays()` seems to be Microsoft specific because the documentation is in MSDN.  Possibly an IronPython specific function?  It is definitely not a standard Python `datetime` as it is not in https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**DateTime is an immutable struct.** When you call [`AddDays()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) or `AddTicks()` it returns a *new instance of a DateTime*, it does NOT modify the instance you called it on. Make sure you assign the result to a variable or there is no visible change in your code:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
d1 = d1.AddDays(-1); // assign back to see the new instance
```

If you need to reset the time portion of the date to midnight, you will need to use an explicit constructor call:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime d2 = new DateTime( d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, 0, 0, 0 );
DateTime d3 = d1.Date; // a simpler alternative to the above...
```

Comment: Your reset to midnight is overly complicated - `DateTime d2 = d1.Date` is sufficient for stripping the time component off.

Comment: "DateTime is an immutable struct." - nuff said =D

Answer (score 15):

the easiest way is this..

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);
```

now if you are trying to use a variable that has already been created, you would do this...

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now;  // will give you today's date
yesterday = yesterday.Date.AddDays(-1); // will give you yesterday's date at 12:00 AM
```

Possibly posting your code will show us what you are doing wrong.

Comment: ... or even DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this:

```
var yesterday = System.DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe your problem is `AddDays` doesn't modify the object, it returns an DateTime with the changed days. So it should be:

```
DateTime Yesterday = CurrentDay.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Up point for being the only answer that actually read the question since this sets the time of day to 00:00:00.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<DateTime>.Date.AddDays(-1);
```

This will strip off the time and give you midnight the previous day.

EDIT:
Yes sorry, I meant to put some sort of indication that "DateTime" meant the variable in question. I added brackets around it.

Comment: that should be `DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);`

Answer (score -1):

### // get Lat Day Of Current Month

```
DateTime newDate= new DateTime();
var LastDay2 =  newDate.AddMonths(1);
var LastDay3 = LastDay2.Day * (-1);
var d5 = LastDay2.AddDays(LastDay3);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all