# Get one year back from current date

Tags: c#

I want to get exactly one year back from the current date (which I am passing) in .Net. Can anyone provide me a function or code that will perform this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get previous day using datetime.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493724/how-to-get-previous-day-using-datetime)

Answer (score 60):

You can use the [AddYears()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx) method:

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears( -1 );
```

Answer (score 13):

Try [`DateTime.AddYears(-1);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

```
    public DateTime YearEarlier(DateTime mydate)
{
  return mydate.AddYears(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DateTime.AddYears(-1);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like always, leap years make thing funny. If you have (I used embedded Boo interpreter on the SharpDevelop, thus the Boo syntax)

```
leap = DateTime(2004,2,29)
prev = leap.AddDays(-1)
Console.WriteLine(leap.AddYears(-1))
Console.WriteLine(prev.AddYears(-1))
```

you get the same day.