# How to calculate Today's with previous days or next days in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

Today,

Suppose, I have a book which is borrowed from library for 7 days & book repay last date 20/12/2013. Tomorrow the book's validity will be 6 days.

I want to calculate last date with today. How to I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get previous day using datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493724/how-to-get-previous-day-using-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

```
Datetime lastdate = DateTime .Today .AddDays (-6);
DateTime nextdate = DateTime .Today .AddDays (6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You and add a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get another `DateTime` using the [`add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_addition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operator

```
var expirationDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(6);
```

Comment: I want just Date not time. Please solve it... Thanks Dude!!